# Cannot Login with Excel VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

So I am tryin to create a Script that will automatically login for me on this website:

https://teespring.com/login

This is my script so far:

```
Sub openBrowser()

'Open new browser
Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

'Navigate to Website
urlWebsite = "https://teespring.com/login"
driver.Get urlWebsite
```

So I have tried to enter my username  with the following lines of code:

```
driver.FindElementByCss("").sendKeys Username
```

But I got an error saying element not visible

Is there any way I can still automate the login process?

thanks for your help and if you need further information I will try my best to as I am still learning how to handle vba selenium :-)

Comment: You may need to wait for that particular page element to load before you attempt to interact with it. Something like: `do while el is nothing: on error resume next: set el = driver.findelementbycss(""): on error goto 0: loop` -- and maybe have a DoEvents or secondary exit condition to prevent infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not visible because it is inside a form.

[image: Login fields in form]

You need to access via form:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://teespring.com/login"
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        With .FindElementByClass("js-email-login-form")
            .FindElementByCss("input[name=email]").SendKeys "myEmail"
            .FindElementByCss("input[name=password]").SendKeys "myPassWord"
            .FindElementByCss("input[type=submit]").Click
        End With
        Stop '<==  Delete me after inspection
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```